# Pairing Real Android Phone with Emulator Through Bluetooth

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluetooth

I have an android application which depends on Bluetooth. Now I need two devices for using this but I only have one physical android device. Is there any way in which I can use my device and my PC emulator as terminals while the PC emulator uses the PC's bluetooth adapter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. Simple answer, but emulator does not support bluetooth. I develop bluetooth accessories for Android and have been waiting for BT access from the emulator but for now, the simple answer is NO.